# React Native - get value from horizontal picker

Tags: react-native, mobile

I would like to use horizontal picker from here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vseslav/react-native-horizontal-picker)

But how can I get a current selected value?

```
<HorizontalPicker
                data={this.getGameActivities()}
                renderItem={this.renderActivityItem}
                itemWidth={80}
                onChange={this.setState({selected: ???})}
                                />
```

I was trying to update my state in renderActivityItem (I know it's not good) function, but got error with Maximum update depth exceeded. Can anybody help me how to get selected value?

Comment: How's your data?

Comment: `onChange={(position) => this.setState({selected: position})}` `position` is the currently selected item index (according to docs). so, you can get the value with `this.state.selected`. `this.getGameActivities()[this.state.selected]` is your currently selected item

Comment: Uğur Eren thanks a lot, I couldnt figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UseState hook.
For example:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

<HorizontalPicker
  data={itemList}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  itemWidth={60}
  onChange={setValue}
  defaultIndex={0}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing parameter inside your onChange attribute

```
                <HorizontalPicker
                data={this.getGameActivities()}
                renderItem={this.renderActivityItem}
                itemWidth={80}
                onChange={(selected) => this.setState({selected})} 
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it in this way:

```
    <HorizontalPicker
            data={this.getGameActivities()}
            renderItem={this.renderActivityItem}
            itemWidth={80}
            onChange={(val) => this.functionName(val)}
                            />
```